# replace passenger side engine mount camry 05 2.4 L

Tags: camry, diy, motor-mounts

I am planning to replace passenger side motor mount in my 2005 Camry with 170K miles on it. I have craftsman floor jack and two jack stands. Do you thing it is DIY job to replace motor mount? Is it safe to jack up engine by oil pan after lifting car on jack stands? Do I need to loosen up any hose or any cables on engine to do this job?

Comment: Which engine do you have? If you're going to use a jack on the oil pan make sure you have a piece of wood in between.

Comment: 2.4 L engine @Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC it's kind of a PITA to remove the right hand lower engine mount. You need a sufficient amount of lift to clear the stud on top of the mount. It's possible to do but you might want to consider loosening the other engine mount bolts to assist. While it might take some more time I think you can remove the engine mount bracket from the block. Again, IIRC this takes more time than it's worth. When you have other means to remove the mount.

Use a piece of wood on if you need to jack up the engine on the oil pan. Make sure you have some longish pry bars to assist the removal of the mount.